# The process of using Metasploit to get in Systems

Tags: firewalls, metasploit

I am new in metasploit. I get the basic concept of exploiting a system or whatever your trying to do. You find a vulnerability in a system, you use an exploit or make one. Doing that on your local network is easy, but doing that on a computer across the globe is something else. There is the system's firewall, the router's firewall, and there might be other programs that keeps you away from success. On top of that, the exploit may not succeed. I get that the previous theories may block the process, but I don't know how Metasploit tells you that. I tried to exploit a machine running Windows XP that is not in my network with netapi exploit (the firewall of that machine is off), but I got errors like the connection refused by the host. I tried another exploit that uses windows/meterpreter/bind_tcp payload but i get: failed to bind to -my IP address_the port i used-.

So am having some real rough times using metasploit on global ipv4 addresses. So telling me the process of attacking a system across the globe and the types of problems I could face with metasploit and how to fix them will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think this is not a metasploit problem, but a basic networking knowledge issue. Does your attacker machine have direct access to the victim IP?

Comment: i have his IP that has some open ports on it

Comment: That's not what I asked. Do you have direct access to that IP?

Comment: no i dont have it

Comment: Then your attempts will fail. You need access to the machine.

Comment: @schroeder What exactly do you mean by "***direct*** *access"* *?*

Comment: Can the attacker machine send traffic directly to the victim machine? If you are using the victim's public IP address (assigned to a router, for instance) then you are sending traffic to the router, not the victim machine.

Comment: emmm, i am using his public ip, so what do i need to send the traffic directly to him?